# How can I generate path relative to the target file generated by gulp-inject

Tags: npm, gulp, gulp-inject

I am using gulp-inject to inject some css and js files to the `dist/index.html` which are located at `dist/css/*.css` and `dist/js/*.js`

```
gulp.task('prep-index', function () {
  var target = gulp.src('./dist/index.html');
  var sources = gulp.src(['./dist/js/*.js', './dist/css/*.css'], {read: false}, {relative: true});

  return target.pipe(inject(sources))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

Currently it is injecting files from the base url of the project, but I want it to inject files links relative from target file i.e. `dist/index.html`

from `/dist/css/*.css` to `css/*.css`

and from `/dist/js/*.js` to `js/*.js`

But its generating like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Directi Task</title>
    <!-- inject:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/css/basscss.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/css/style.css">
    <!-- endinject -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- inject:js -->
    <script src="/dist/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/dist/js/script.min.js"></script>
    <!-- endinject -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Any tips on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the bug, the `{relative: true}` should be inside the `inject()` but not within `src()`

`return target.pipe(inject(sources, {relative: true}))` fixed the problem.